# dlinfo(... SERPATH ...) C++ wrapper

Tags: c++

**dlfcn.h** is a library of C functions to work with dynamic dependencies (shared objects). I've been experimenting with wrapping them in a C++ API, mostly as practice in making a C++ wrapper.

This is an excerpt of my process of wrapping the `Dl_serinfo` parts of [`dlinfo(...)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html) in the C library. For reference:

> ```
> typedef struct {
>     size_t dls_size;           /* Size in bytes of
>                                 the whole buffer */
>     unsigned int dls_cnt;      /* Number of elements
>                                 in 'dls_serpath' */
>     Dl_serpath dls_serpath[1]; /* Actually longer,
>                                 'dls_cnt' elements */
> } Dl_serinfo;
> ```

And `Dl_serpath`:

> ```
> typedef struct {
>     char *dls_name;            /* Name of library search
>                                 path directory */
>     unsigned int dls_flags;    /* Indicates where this
>                                 directory came from */
> } Dl_serpath;
> ```

Note that the `dls_serpath` member of `Dl_serinfo` is a "flexible array member" and the entire `Dl_serinfo` struct is supposed to be allocated with enough space for `dls_cnt` entries in the array.

---

My wrapper:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>

namespace dl {
class dl_error : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class serinfo;
class serpath {
    friend class serinfo;

private:
    std::string_view name_;
    unsigned int flags_;

    explicit serpath(::Dl_serpath path)
        : name_(path.dls_name)
        , flags_(path.dls_flags)
    {}

public:
    std::string_view name() const { return name_; }
    unsigned int flags() const { return flags_; }
};

class serinfo {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> bytes;

public:
    explicit serinfo(void* dlhandle) {
        ::Dl_serinfo size;

        if (::dlinfo(dlhandle, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, &size)) {
            throw dl_error(::dlerror());
        }

        bytes = std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(size.dls_size);
        if (::dlinfo(dlhandle, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, bytes.get())) {
            throw dl_error(::dlerror());
        }

        if (::dlinfo(dlhandle, RTLD_DI_SERINFO, bytes.get())) {
            throw dl_error(::dlerror());
        }
    }

    unsigned int cnt() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<::Dl_serinfo const*>(bytes.get())->dls_cnt;
    }

    dl::serpath serpath(unsigned int index) const {
        return dl::serpath(
            reinterpret_cast<::Dl_serinfo const*>(bytes.get())->dls_serpath[index]);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class dl_error : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

Given the purpose of this class, it seems logical to have it get the most recent error automatically. Especially since there is a gotcha involved, where `dlerror()` will return `NULL` if called a second time (so if some coder checks `dlerror()` to print or log the error message, and then does `dl_error{::dlerror()}`… boom). Plus it just makes it so much easier to use: `throw dl_error{};` is just so much more ergonomic than `throw dl_error{::dlerror()};`.

Also, given that this class is already in namespace `dl`, it seems superfluous to have a prefix. `dl::error` is much nicer than `dl::dl_error`.

```
class serpath
```

Eh, I mean, is it really that much more painful to type out `search_path` (or `search_path_info`, given that it’s actually a path and some (in theory) flags)?

If you’re doing a thin wrapper around a C library, then it’s okay to recreate the C library’s shitty names. But that doesn’t look like what you’re doing, so why not use human-readable names? For someone whose first language isn’t English, the following is damn-near illegible:

```
auto const paths = dl::serinfo{dlhandle};

auto const path = paths.serpath(paths.cnt() - 1);
```

Compare that to:

```
auto const paths = dl::get_search_paths_for(dlhandle);

auto const path = paths[paths.size() - 1];
```

Every semi-competent C++ programmer will understand what `size()` and `operator[]` mean, and the function name is pretty much self-documenting. Meanwhile, `ser` isn’t even short for `search` (“serch” path?), and `cnt` just sounds rude.

Coders shouldn’t need to keep a translation guide open at hand to be able to read code, stopping every two lines to translate `dl_serinfopathxyzagiuasgtha` to something human-legible. 90% of the verbiage in good C++ code disappears into `auto` and the like anyway (and the fact that you need way fewer function calls than in C code), so take advantage of that and spell things out clearly.

```
class serpath {
    // ... [snip] ...

    std::string_view name_;
```

This is *extremely* unwise. I get that you’re trying to avoid unnecessary allocations, and you *assume* that the string `name_` references will be owned by a `serinfo` object which will outlive the `serpath` object. But there’s nothing in the interface of either class that suggests that, let alone requires it. What’s to stop someone from doing:

```
auto get_particular_library_search_path(void* dlhandle)
{
    auto const info = dl::serinfo{dlhandle};

    for (auto i = 0u; i < info.cnt(); ++i)
    {
        auto const sp = info.serpath(i);
    
        if (satisfies_some_condition(sp))
            return sp;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"not found"};
}
```

If you’re going to keep this interface, then it might be wise to use a `shared_ptr` rather than a `unique_ptr` in `serinfo`, and pass a copy of that to every `serpath` you create. Copying `shared_ptr` is cheap (it’s actually *destroying* shared pointers that is fairly costly, but not really that much). That way, even if the original `serinfo` is destroyed, the `serpath`s won’t dangle.

Alternately, perhaps, you could make `serpath` non-copyable and non-movable, then create an array of them at construction time, and return references to them. Or, even simpler, just return a reference to the `Dl_serpath` `struct` directly. Because why not? All you’re doing with `serpath` is converting the `char*` to a `string_view`… and you don’t really gain all that much by that. (In fact, you *lose* info, because it’s very likely the user might want to use the returned path(s) with some system call or other, but you can’t use `string_view` because it isn’t `NUL`-terminated. You’d need to convert the `string_view` to a `string` to do pretty much anything useful with it anyway.)

Frankly, I’d just use a `string` (or possibly a `std::filesystem::path`!) in `serpath`, and all of this risk and hassle vanishes. Yeah, sure, you’re paying for the cost of a string allocation… but compared to all the costs involved in the allocation for `serinfo`, all those system calls, and so on… meh. The safety and ease of use is so much more worth it compared to avoiding a single, likely small allocation on what is certainly never going to be a hot path.

```
class serpath {

    // ... [snip] ...

    std::string_view name_;
    unsigned int flags_;

    // ... [snip] ...

public:
    std::string_view name() const { return name_; }
    unsigned int flags() const { return flags_; }
```

Are getters really necessary? Why couldn’t you just do:

```
class serpath
{
    friend class serinfo;

    explicit serpath(::Dl_serpath path)
        : name(path.dls_name)
        , flags(path.dls_flags)
    {}

public:
    std::string name; // perhaps better: std::filesystem::path path;
    unsigned int flags;
};
```

There doesn’t seem to be any gain from using getter functions for this simple return-value `struct`.

```
class serinfo
```

The thing that strikes me most about this class is that it’s actually a container of `serpath`s. All of the gymnastics you do in the constructor is really just to get that array of `Dl_serpath`, then dole it out safely. In theory, the class could be this:

```
class serinfo
{
    std::vector<serpath> _paths; // assuming serpath uses string, not string_view

public:
    
    explicit serinfo(void* dlhandle)
    {
        // everything the same as your current constructor, except `bytes` is
        // a local variable

        // then:

        _paths.reserve(bytes->dls_cnt);
        for (auto i = 0u; i < bytes->dls_cnt; ++i)
            _paths.push_back(serpath{bytes->dls_serpath[i]});
    }

    auto size() const noexcept { return _paths.size(); }

    // same for all the other useful const vector functions:
    // begin, end, operator[], etc.
};
```

I’m not suggesting it *should* be like this; there’s no point in allocating the `Dl_serinfo` structure, then just duplicating that allocation in the vector to copy all the data over. I’m just illustrating that it *could* be like this to make the point that `serinfo` is basically an immutable container of `serpath`s… so its interface should reflect that.

If you did implement a container interface, you could do stuff like:

```
// printing all the search paths
for (auto const& [path, _] : dl::get_search_paths_for(dlhandle))
    std::cout << path << '\n';
```

Note that you don’t need the *entire* container interface. All you need are `const` versions of `begin()`, `end()`, `size()`, and maybe `empty()`. If you wanted, you could add `operator[]` for convenience, but that’s pretty much it.

```
bytes = std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(size.dls_size);
```

This *might* work… if `alignof(::Dl_serinfo) >= __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`.

See, `std::malloc()` always allocates with alignment `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. Presumably `::Dl_serinfo` doesn’t have any special alignment requirements (you don’t need to use `std::aligned_alloc()` to allocate it), so `std::malloc()` will never allocate *under*-aligned memory for `::Dl_serinfo`, though it may allocate *over*-aligned memory, but that’s not a problem (other than a tiny amount of wasted memory, I suppose).

But `new` uses `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`… which may be more *or less* than `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. If you did `new ::Dl_serinfo` directly, there would be no problem; if `alignof(::Dl_serinfo) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`, then `new` would automatically fix the alignment for you.

But you’re doing `new std::byte[sizeof(::Dl_serinfo)]` (basically). You’re not allocating a `::Dl_serinfo`, you’re allocating bytes (which have an alignment of 1, though `new` will naturally use `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`). So you need to be sure that the memory is properly aligned.

You could just use a static assert like:

```
static_assert(__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ >= alignof(::Dl_serinfo));
```

That will just kill the compilation if there is a danger of alignment problems.

A better solution is to make sure the alignment is correct:

```
// in constructor:
constexpr auto alignment = std::align_val_t{alignof(::Dl_serinfo)};

bytes.reset(new (alignment) std::byte[size.dls_size]);
// note: can't use make_unique(), but doesn’t really matter
```

All the calls to `::dlinfo()` look like this:

```
if (::dlinfo(/*...*/)) {
    throw dl_error(::dlerror());
}
```

For starters, I think you should make the error class more ergonomic:

```
if (::dlinfo(/*...*/)) {
    throw error{};
}
```

But also, simply converting the result of the `::dlinfo()` call to `bool` doesn’t really give the best sense of what is actually going on here. I have no way of knowing whether maybe `::dlinfo()` actually returns `bool` or something, or who knows what else, or what it means. [You should generally not add redundant `!=` or `==` to conditions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es87-dont-add-redundant--or--to-conditions)… but the guideline is actually more subtle; it says adding redundant tests is unwise when there are only two meaningful values (like a valid pointer value and `nullptr`). With integers, there are often several meaningful values. It would be more clear to explain that you’re explicitly testing for “not zero” like this:

```
if (::dlinfo(/*...*/) != 0) {
    throw error{};
}
```

When I read that, even without looking up the `::dlinfo()` API, I immediately understand, okay, this function returns zero on success.

One final thing: I’m not a fan of constructors that do more than *just* construct objects. `serinfo`’s constructor is more than just a constructor of `serinfo` objects. It’s actually doing a series of queries first, *and then using the results* to construct the object. That’s a violation of the single-responsibility principle.

Besides, you’re “doing a thing”… not “making a thing”. You’re “getting the search paths for a shared object”… you’re not “making a `serinfo` object”. The latter only happens as a side-effect of the former, but it’s not *really* the `serinfo` object you want… it’s the paths.

“Doing a thing” usually means you want a function, not a constructor. I think that’s especially important when you’re doing a thing that might fail, because then you can give the user the option of avoiding exceptions in cases where they can’t afford them. In other words, you could do:

```
class serinfo
{
private:
    explicit serinfo(std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> data) :
        _data{std::move(data)}
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> _data;

    friend auto get_search_paths_for(handle h) -> expected<serinfo>;

    // ... [snip] ...
};

// using something similar to the proposed std::expected:
auto get_search_paths_for(handle h) -> expected<serinfo>
{
    auto size = ::Dl_serinfo{};

    if (::dlinfo(h, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, &size) != 0)
        return make_unexpected(dl_error{});

    auto buffer = std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]>{};
    try
    {
        auto p = new (std::align_val_t{alignof(::Dl_serinfo)}) std::byte[size.dls_size];

        buffer.reset(p);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return make_unexpected(std::current_exception());
    }

    if (::dlinfo(h, RTLD_DI_SERINFOSIZE, buffer.get()) != 0)
        return make_unexpected(dl_error{});

    if (::dlinfo(h, RTLD_DI_SERINFO, buffer.get()) != 0)
        return make_unexpected(dl_error{});

    return serinfo{std::move(buffer)};
}
```

With usage like:

```
// I absolutely cannot tolerate an exception here:
if (auto const search_paths = dl::get_search_paths_for(dlhandle); search_paths)
{
    // do something with *search_paths
}
else
{
    // report error somehow
}

// Exceptions are okay here:
auto const search_paths = *dl::get_search_paths_for(dlhandle);
// if there was an error, it will be automatically rethrown
```

Once you do this, you open the door to allowing no-fail default-constructed `serinfo` objects, which internally just have a null pointer, but externally present as an empty list of search paths. And once you have that, you can trivially implement no-fail moving and swapping, which are *very* handy in general. Plus, being able to default construct things is handy in a lot of ways (like reading stuff from streams, for example).

Even if you don’t use something like `expected<T>` and just throw exceptions from the function, I think it’s still a better interface than doing all the work in the constructor on top of actually constructing the object.

Comment: You've given me lots to think about. A few comments on your comments: `dl::dl_error` was because I like names to be unambiguous even sans-namespace. `serinfo`/`serpath`/`cnt` were named specifically to recreate the C library's names without C "namespacing" (`Dl_serinfo`/`Dl_serpath`/`dls_cnt`). The getters were to have the same interface between `serinfo` and `serpath` (if one had to be getters, I figured uniformity was nicer). W.r.t. your superior design, idk how I feel, since I prefer C library wrappers to mimic the library rather than improve on the design. Perhaps another layer on-top.

Comment: Yeah, there are basically 2 strategies to wrapping a C library: an interface that is basically identical, so migrating is mostly trivial (and sometimes free!)… or make an actual, true C++ interface that might look very different, but is more natural to C++ programmers. There are pros and cons to either option. I obviously lean to the latter generally, but meh, that’s a matter of personal preference.